# 2560x1080p not working on 21:9 display in Win10 Geforce 9500 GT HDMI

Tags: resolution, hdmi

The title pretty much sums it up.

I have a GeForce 9500 GT card (it has one DVI and one HDMI connector). [According to its specs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9500-gt/specifications) it should go up to 2560x1600.

Now I tried to connect to an [LG 29UM57](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29UM57-P-ultrawide-led-monitor#tech-specs) using HDMI (no option there, it only has 2 HDMI connectors) but I only get Full HD, not the 21:9.

This is on Windows 10 32-bit. I have the latest nVidia drivers 341.81 installed. I completed cleaned/removed the drivers [after I read this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/3gsi9c/cant_get_monitor_to_switch_to_2560x1080/), still Windows and nVidia control panel only show resolution up to Full HD (1920x1080).

What am I missing?

---

Answers to your questions:

- I used the card's HDMI port as I have no DVI/HDMI adapter lying around.
- Yes I tried setting custom resolution, to the extent that only one more or less white line was shown on the display :(
- @Tetsujin: what "basic" PCI-E x16 model would you consider as "valid" for today :D Would a GT610 be fine?

Comment: Did you use an HDMI, or a DVI port on the video card to connect to the HDMI on the monitor?

Comment: Have you tried setting custom resolution ?

Comment: The LG is an ultra-wide… when that 9500 was made (7 years ago!), no-one had heard of 21:9 resolution. The card is actually just 'scared' of the numbers it's getting from the screen & is dropping back to something it feels 'happy' with. Invest another 20 quid/bucks/shekels in a completely basic modern card, because tbh, that card is probably costing you more in electricity than it's worth in pixel-shifting.

Comment: Indeed, if you take a plain GT610 there are way newer drivers and I found a statement from nVidia that starting with driver release 340 the "old" stuff wouldn't be supported anymore. But they don't consider it "legacy" yet. Oh and it's at least 30$ for a 610 ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Post as an answer and I'll gladly accept. GT610 for 30 bucks with newest drivers did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card was just too old and drivers didn't really support it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a GeForce GT 530 and Windows 8.1

For me this worked: create a custom resolution in *NVIDIA Control Panel*, then it can be selected for the Desktop resolution

Details:

- right click on the desktop and in the menu select *NVIDIA Control Panel*
- there select *Display / Change resolution*
- click the *Customize...* button
- in the *Customize* dialog click the *Create Custom Resolution...* button
- there enter the desired resolution, I used 2560x1440 for my monitor, you enter 2560x1080 (for refresh rate have 60 Hz and 32 bit color depth, Scan type: Progressive)
- important: `Timing Standard` should be set to *CVT reduced blank* (maybe one of the other options will work too, for me they did not)
- click *Test* and if it works, select the resolution in table (still in the *NVIDIA Control Panel*, on the *Display / Change resolution* page)

For me this worked for the desktop, but 3D fullscreen apps still can not use this resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nVidia control panel (download and install as required)

- choose Display -> Change Resolution

  - choose Customize, the LG 29UM57 native resolution is 2560 x 1080, so in Display Mode (as reported by Windows)

    - enter 2560 in horizontal pixels
    - enter 1080 in vertical pixels
    - enter 60 in refresh rate
    - enter 32 bpp in color depth
    - choose "Progressive" in Scan type
  - in Timing

    - choose "CVT reduced blank" in Standard
    - and then click the "Test" button
    - after some mode changing...
    - if the screen is legible and you can read it click success or keep it ...
      and your question was successfully resolved, search for how to adjust 
      true type for your monitor resolution if you need to kill more time
    - if the screen is blank or garbled, wait patiently... 
      the display adapter will revert to its previous settings
      just a few seconds after a sinking feeling of panic sets in,
      but with regret, the resolution that worked for my 9800GT didn't work for you

Comment: Ummm, this question is over 5 years old and this equipment does not exist anymore.